# How to know when a user launch an activity in my app

Tags: android

I have an app that shows a list of places to visit in my province. When users tap somewhere, the app launches a new activity that shows specific information about that place. How can I know that the user has launched the activity of specific information and which of the places was?

Thak you for your time,

flagg327

Comment: This is regarding analytics or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flurry. Create project on flurry.com and it will give you an app id.
download the .jar file and put it in apps "libs" folder.

And then in your activity:
in onCreate():

```
FlurryAgent.init(this, "YOUR_APP_ID");
```

and in onStart() and onStop():

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "YOUR_APP_ID");
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME");

}
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);

}
```

and then when you login to flurry.com, in your project you can see the full log of that activity, even if the app crashed on that activity, you will get crash report.

You can use google analytics also.

Answer (score 1):

When you start your activity add extras to the intent.

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("KEY", "VALUE");
    startActivity(newIntent);
```

Then from your second activity retrieve the data bundled with that intent.

```
    String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY");
```

Comment: But that information is within the same device. What I want to do is take that information from any user in any side of the world and send it to me. Thank you.

Comment: then you should make your own server and use network calls to that server

Comment: Oh right, you need a server to collect that information and send network calls to it. Or you can try google analytics or any other analytics platform.

Answer (score 1):

Can use the  package : **android.app.usage**

**Has the following Classes :**
ConfigurationStats ,NetworkStats, NetworkStats.Bucket, NetworkStatsManager , UsageEvents ,  UsageEvents.Event, UsageStatsManager

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html)

Comment: You can also use flurry, google analytics, parse to track your app usage which will be so easy and defined.